# Django channels how to check if a group exists in channel layer?

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a piece of code (django channel consumer) which creates an individual group for each user connected. like this

```
@login_required_connection
async def connect(self):
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.user.id,
        self.channel_name
    )
    await self.accept()
```

Everything meant for that user is pushed to his group from django side, and consumer forwards it to him.

The problem is that if connection breaks for a minute and then reconnects, user does not receive anything pushed within that duration.

What I want to do (please suggest a better approach if there is one) is save data for user in redis and push all data when he reconnects.

My question is, how can I check if a group for user exists or not? so that I can save data to cache if does not exist.

**NOTE** Currently I am maintaining online / offline status in redis. (When user connects place a key for him and remove on disconnect). But I just want to check if group exists or not.

Comment: You'll need to save this state somewhere (save the channel_name for the user when he joins the first time and remove it when he leaves). Looks like saving it in the user session could do the trick, since you're talking about short-lived data.

Comment: @dirkgroten This is what I am doing (I don't have session I am managing state in redis). I thought there may be a better solution. Thanks BTW :)

Comment: yep, using redis for this is also a perfectly good solution.